# Angular infinite scroller directive with reusable cells

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now here's my problem I am building an app which will have an infinite scroll of uploaded photo feed. Whilst I managed to achieve decent performance at around 1000 cells (inside a cell theres an image and many other elements) but past that it gets really choppy.

So my idea is to actually have no more than 5 cells and when one scrolls outside the view its reattached at the end of the list with the content after the last cell. Whilst I am able to write one without angular with ng-repeat I am stuck... Don't really know where to start.

Given dataset of 1000 elements is there a way of me actually not appending this 1000 cells in an infinite scroll but actually having it (Angular) reuse what is currently there?

So far I found tons of plugs that do what I am already doing and they crap out on mobile devices after 100-150 elements as they are mostly for desktop.

Comment: are you using one way binding in these cells? so `{{ ::item.image }}` that increase performance over `{{ item.image }}` because then you aren't creating thousands of watchers for no apparent reason

Comment: No I am not - thanks for that!

Comment: In the end I used the iscroll and wrote reusable directive but not reacting to the changes.